# How to set a value in hidden field according to item selected in drop down list

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a drop down list which i create dynamically:

```
foreach(XmlNode item in doc.SelectNodes("//Monits/Monit")) {
    User newuser = new User();
    newuser.Id = item.SelectSingleNode("Id").InnerText;
    newuser.UserName = item.SelectSingleNode("UserName").InnerText;
    newuser.Email = item.SelectSingleNode("Email").InnerText;
    usersddl.Items.Add(newuser.UserName); //userddl is a tag on aspx              
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to keep the user Id in a hidden field according to item changed in my ddl.
For example I select from drop down list the name Robbie, and his Id will be held in hidden field value attribute.
I dont have more code to show because i dont know where to start...
Help some one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You should declare an event handler for the event on drop down list changed value.
There in this hanlder you could use this one

```
HiddenFieldID.Value=ddl.SelectedValue;
```

When I am saying an event handler, I mean to add in your markup this loc

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

and in your code behind class

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender object, EventArgs e)
{
     HiddenFieldID.Value=ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be ".Value"

Comment: It looks nice but I dont need the selected value (name) I need an other value (Id) according to the name selection..

Comment: Ok, please specify then what do you need exactly in order to correct it correspondigly.